# Ion optics of a gridded ion thruster

Tags: optics, rocket-science, ions

Followup to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/436254/hole-size-in-ion-thrusters-accel-grid-v-scoop-grid/436285?noredirect=1#comment980117_436285).

The holes in the grid of an ion thruster should be thought of as an optical device for ions. As is shown [here](http://projects-web.engr.colostate.edu/ionstand/research/research_ionoptics.php), ions are focused to the center of the stream. My question is how?

Thinking about the grid as a single hole, this would be two charged cylinders behind a plasma. I would expect the electric fields within the cylinders to be parallel to the cylinders axis. The Plasma is a bit more complicated, since removing ions there will bulge in the plasma-sheath. But assuming the bulged in field is approximately spherical, any sideways-forces should add up to zero. (I assume the plasma is a near perfect conductor.)

There is a magnetic field applied to the plasma, but I expect it to be irrelevant for this specific process since [simulating this process does not require external magnetic fields](https://erps.spacegrant.org/uploads/images/images/iepc_articledownload_1988-2007/2001index/2002iepc/papers/t09/101_4.pdf).

I may add that I suspect the system to behave similar to the [einzel-lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einzel_lens), though wikipedia's article did not help; an explanation for why the fringe fields are deformed this much inwards is missing and the schematic field lines are impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [detailed explanation](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1005034/files/p27.pdf) (especially section 5.3). Essentially, second order terms of the electrostatic potential can't be ignored.

But to supply a graphical explanation:

[image: equipotential lines near a central hole]
([More detailed graphics](https://www.plasmacontrols.com/uploads/7/6/0/4/76049785/1081827_orig.jpg), the [source page for the image above](http://projects-web.engr.colostate.edu/ionstand/research/research_ionoptics.php) features a broken video link, [found replacement here](http://projects-web.engr.colostate.edu/ionstand/research/video/Ion%20Optics%20Beam%20Ions.mp4).)

The left most image shows equipotential lines in color. Following e.g. the yellow region, it is visible the potential bulges towards the plasma. The electric field is always perpendicular to these lines, so the acceleration vectors of ions would point towards the axis, allowing them to be focused through the smaller hole in the accel-grid.

Another way to derive the same conclusion is to look at the right image. It is clear the plasma sheath is bulged in. At the edge, the plasma may be viewed as perfect conductor, so the electric potential has to be equal at the sheath. Again, this requires electric field lines perpendicular to the sheath and therefore the initial acceleration of the ions is towards the axis.